# How does Tensorflow allocate GPU memory for Conv2D operation?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I traced the gpu usage during training and for `conv2d` operation, it shows:

[image: Tensorboard node info for conv2d]

I tried to calculate the exact memory need for this op with `(3*3*3*16 + 32*450*450*3+ 32*448*448*16) * 4/(1024**2)` which equals 466.16MB. Obviously, TensorFlow allocates 318MB more memory for `Conv2d`. Why Would TF do that?

Answer (score 0):

The internal implementation of conv2d might need to use temporary storage unrelated to the size of the output.